# different route and auth for the same action in the .net core 2 mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have an action in my ASP.NET Core controller. This action has multiple routes:

```
public class TestController
{
    [HttpGet("test1")]
    [HttpGet("test2")]
    public async Task<object> Test()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

These two routes require different access rights, the following:

- route:`test/test1` need to have `role1` permission
- route:`test/test2` need to have `role2` permission

I'm override the `HttpGet` class and implement `IAuthorizationFilter` interface:

```
public class AuthGet : HttpGet, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AuthGet(string template,string roleName) : base(template)
    {
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        //check auth
    }
}
```

Then, I'm replacing `HttpGet` with `AuthGet`. This way, both AuthGet's `OnAuthorization` will execute. But I can't distinguish between `test/test1` and `test/test2`.

How do I determine different permissions based on different routes on an `Action`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to keep this to a single method. Simply create `private` method to do the actual work and create two Actions that simply the return the value of that `private` method:

```
[AuthGet("test1", "role1")]
public async Task<object> Test1()
{
    return await Test(1);
}

[AuthGet("test2", "role2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test2()
{
    return await Test(2);
}

private async Task<object> Test(int testRoute)
{
    if (testRoute == 1)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do somthing else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I tried to use `AuthGetAttribute.Template` to match the `context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template` in the `OnAuthorization` method to determine if authorization verification is required. This method seems to work.